# What is this notification symbol for?

Tags: notification-icons

I’ve circled the icon in red. What is this notification/alert for?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This icon has to do with parent supervision. This means that someone is supervising your mobile phone and that your mobile is in a kind of "children's mode". Can you click on it?